# Remove items of type from List

Tags: java, list

I keep coming across techniques like the code below where i need to filter out a type of enumeration from a list.

Are there any more efficent ways to do this?

```
    private List<TestResult> removeInfo(List<TestResult> testResults) {
    List<TestResult> tmpT = new ArrayList<TestResult>();
    for(TestResult t : testResults) {
        if(!t.getSeverity().equals(Severity.INFO)) {
            tmpT.add(t);
        }
    }
    return tmpT;
}
```

Collections would be my first thought but not sure.

Cheers
D

Comment: I think you'd get some improvement by using an actual iterator and a LinkedList, because the removals would be O(1).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: How does these objects end up in the list?I mean you remove here the `Severity.INFO` but another part of the code created and used it right?

Comment: Correct, it does get used but in this instance it's so i don't have to pass the many Severity.INFO to the front end - only need to use warnings and errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the list in-place using an iterator:

```
Iterator<TestResult> iterator = testResults.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    TestResult result = iterator.next();
    if (!result.getSeverity().equals(Severity.INFO)) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}

//Now testResults contains all elements that do not have Severity of INFO
```

This is an example of Marvo's comment. It's more memory efficient but just time efficient as your code. Again, as Marvo said you could some improvement by using a LinkedList. However, unless you're dealing with huge lists of data I don't think you'll notice a difference.

Comment: Cheers,the list could have about 1-2000 results. makes perfect sense to edit the list rather than create a new one

Answer (score 0):

Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has some efficient ways to this:

```
private Iterable<TestResults> removeInfo(List<TestResults> list){
    return Iterables.filter(list, new Predicate<TestResults>(){
        public boolean apply(TestResults input){
            return !input.getSeverity.equals(Severity.INFO);
        }
    }
}
```

This does not copy the data at all, and still works if the List's Iterator does not support remove.

Comment: nice, i'll put this forward but it's always a fuss when new jars get added to the system but if it improves the system then why not!

Comment: I would highly recommend it. Guava is an amazingly useful library, for collections, IO, functional, etc.

Comment: It does indeed, we have looked into this today and is the route we're going to take, cheers.